# How to tell if Java is running as a windows service and if the -Xrs flag is being used

Tags: java, windows, service

One reoccurring problem with our Java application on Windows is that customers are running it as a Windows service without specifying the Java -Xrs flag. This way when the administrator logoff the Windows machine the Java process receives a termination signal and terminates thus causing what seems to be a random production down situation.

I would like to add to the server log files and monitoring tool a warning about this configuration problem. 
In order to do that I would like to know:
1. Is my Java application running as a Windows service ?
2. Is the -Xrs flag specified as part of the java.exe command ?
Any ideas how to achieve this are welcomed.

Comment: I just "converted" a Java app to Win service, using https://nssm.cc  When I logoff, the app survives. The "server" is a Windows XP, with JRE 1.7_80, and I am using -Djava.awt.headless=true    What do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

Found how to check for the -Xrs flag, still need to determine if running as a service:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.util.List;

public class GetCommandLineFlags {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(new GetCommandLineFlags().isReducedSignal());
   }

   public boolean isReducedSignal() {
      List<String> flags = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments();
      for (String flag : flags) {
         if ("-Xrs".equals(flag)) {
            return true;
         }
      }
      return false;
   }

}
```